# Update JIRA ticket status using REST API

Tags: curl, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am able to create a ticket in JIRA using CURL command and having a json data handy.

> curl -D- -u : -X POST --data @< filename> -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://< hostname>:< port>/rest/api/2/issue/

I was now trying to update the status of the ticket generated but was getting the following error.
`{"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"status":"Field 'status' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."}}`

Curl command:

> curl -D- -u < user>:< pwd> -X PUT --data @data_update.txt -H
>   "Content-Type: application/json"
>   http://< hostname>:8100/rest/api/2/issue/MTF-3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Status is not a field in Jira and thus changing the same on fly is not possible. JIRA API doesn’t have provision for that.

We have to follow the transitions and change accordingly.

First, execute   ‘http://localhost:8100/rest/api/latest/issue/MTF -2/transitions?expand=transitions.fields
and know the id’s for transitions.

For Eg: transition id for “Stop Progress” is 31, for “Done” is 41.

Once that is known, use the following link by adding values pertaining to your environment:

```
curl -D- -u <USER>:<PASS> -X POST --data '{"transition":{"id":"<TRANSITION_ID>"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" <JIRA_URL>:<JIRA_PORT>/rest/api/latest/issue/<JIRA_ISSUE>/transitions?expand=transitions.fields
```

**Reference:** Check *Paul grants* answer - 
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/107630/jira-how-to-change-issue-status-via-rest

Comment: When I execute the first command, I get an empty transitions array. Then after executing the second command with transition id of 5, I get an internal server error.

Comment: can we not set the status while creating issue? Mean in the same request while creating issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me since long using R. similar approach should be possible with curl which is used by the 'httr' library.

```
library(httr)
library(RJSONIO)

x <- list(fields = list(project = c(key = "xxxxxxx"), 
                        status = "Assign",
                        issuetype = c(name = "xxxx"),
                        summary = "xxxxxxx",
                        description = "xxxxxxx",
                        customfield_xxxxxx = c(value = "xxxxxx"),
                        assignee = c(name = "userid"),
                        customfield_xxxxxx = "xxxxxxxx"
            ))

# can add more fields as shown above

response <- POST("https://xxxxxxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/",body = toJSON(x), 
                  authenticate(username,passcode, "basic"), 
                  add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json"), 
                  verbose()
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to programtically mark an Issue as Done, you need to either 1) traverse through all of the workflow steps or 2) set this setting for Done:

[image]

The rest api call is then something like this:

```
curl --location 'https://yourdomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/ISSUE-KEY/transitions' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic blah blah
--data '{ "transition": {
    "id": "91"
    }
```