# How to add fixVersions value of a story and change the status in the story of JIRA using REST API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to add fixVersions value for a stroy and change the status in the story of JIRA using REST API and getting error in for the request call

**Info :** Added the proper credentials

**Req 1** - To set fixVersions :

**Url :** <JIRA_URL>:<JIRA_PORT>/rest/api/2/issue/<JIRA_ISSUE>

**Body :**

```
{
"update": {
"fixVersions": [
{"add": 
{"name": "r1.0"}
}
]
}
}
```

[FixVersions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpk5b.png)

**Req 2** To update the Status to accepted :

**Url :** <JIRA_URL>:<JIRA_PORT>/rest/api/2/issue/<JIRA_ISSUE>

**Body :**

```
     {
    "update": {
        "comment": [{
            "add": {
                "body": "Comment body"
            }
        }]
    },
    "fields": {},
    "transition": {
        "id": "41"
    }
}
```

With PUT method :

[PUT METHOD - Change Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cnjwu.png)

**Error :**

```
{
    "errorMessages": [
        "Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: com.quisapps.jira.fieldsecurity.filter.RequestWrapper$1@171c9b81; line: 3, column: 5] (through reference chain: com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueUpdateBean[\"update\"])"
    ]
}
```

**Status Code :** 400 Bad Request

With POST method :

[POST METHOD - Change Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFn42.png)

**Status Code :** 204 No Content

**Referred below links not useful my case :**

1. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809831/update-jira-ticket-status-using-rest-api#:~:text=First%2C%20execute%20'http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost,for%20%E2%80%9CDone%E2%80%9D%20is%2041](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809831/update-jira-ticket-status-using-rest-api#:%7E:text=First%2C%20execute%20%27http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost,for%20%E2%80%9CDone%E2%80%9D%20is%2041).
2. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Using-REST-to-set-fixVersions/qaq-p/1642952
3. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Error-while-trying-to-update-a-custom-field-using-REST-API/qaq-p/699080

How to deal with above issues ? Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen set the following work (but this replaces the current value):

```
    {
      "update": { 
        "fixVersions": [ { "set": [ {"name": "r1.0"} ] } ]
      }
    }
```

I am still looking for a way to push additional values.

Comment: {
      "update": { 
        "fixVersions": [ { "add": [ {"name": "r1.2"} ] } ]
      }
    }